# Practical guide to programming paradigms?

Tags: design-patterns

I think I might be misunderstanding the whole thing and I am looking for some programming wisdom.
When faced with a programming challenge, I feel the most important question is "which programming paradigm(s) are better suited to handle it, and how to apply them". A distant second is "which language to use".
Yet it seems that most of the programming related content I stumble upon on the Internet has it exactly backwards and focuses mostly on the language choice.
An object-oriented solution is fundamentaly the same, whether it's implemented in c++, Java or PHP...
So where is the paradigm centered content?
Where is the "practical guide to programming paradigms and implementations" and other literature helping bringing real-world and programming concepts together?
Note: I already know about "Programming Paradigms for Dummies: What Every Programmer Should Know" from Peter Van Roy.

Answer (score 0):

That would only work if you were completely comfortable with all possible programming paradigms. Few people are, so it makes more sense to take a pragmatic approach and ask "Which programming language that I know well is best suited for solving this particular problem?"

Comment: OTOH: If you were equally ignorant of almost all programming languages, I could see where this question would have merit.